# getting error message related to basicHttpBinding even though I'm using wsHttpBinding

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I am trying to expose a WCF service at a wsHttpBinding endpoint and it gives me the following error message :

> Contract requires Session, but Binding
>   'BasicHttpBinding' doesn't support it
>   or isn't configured properly to
>   support it.

Here is the interface :

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace="http://server.com/orderservices/",SessionMode=SessionMode.Required)]
public interface IOrderService
{
    [OperationContract(IsInitiating=true,IsTerminating=false)]
    string GetOrderNumber();

    [OperationContract(IsInitiating = false, IsTerminating = true)]
    void CreateOrder(string orderXML);
}
```

Here is my web.config file (the service is hosted in IIS 7 ) :

```
<system.serviceModel>
   <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
         <binding name="longTimeoutBinding" 
             receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00">
         </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
   </bindings>
   <services>
      <service name="eMidWare.OrderService">
         <host>
            <baseAddresses>
                <add baseAddress = "http://localhost/" />
            </baseAddresses>
         </host>
         <!-- Service Endpoints -->
         <endpoint 
            address="" 
            binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="longTimeoutBinding"
            contract="eMidWare.IPricingDataService">
         </endpoint>
         <endpoint 
             address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
   </services>
   <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
         <behavior>
            <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True" />
         </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
   </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: @marc_s, I can't even access the service locally using a browser pointing to the .svc file.

Comment: check my answer - I think your config and service contract file don't match....

Comment: Your example shows IOrderService contract and your configuration uses IPricingDataService contract. Where is IOrderService used?

Comment: @Ladislav, thanks. I just corrected out that mistake, but I still get the same error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmmm.... check your service contract - it's a `IOrderService`

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace="http://server.com/orderservices/",SessionMode=SessionMode.Required)]
public interface IOrderService
{
}
```

but in your config, you're setting up an endpoint for `eMidWare.IPricingDataService`

```
<endpoint 
    address="" 
    binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="longTimeoutBinding"
    contract="eMidWare.IPricingDataService">
```

Therefore, I believe, .NET / WCF 4 will kick in a default endpoint, which is of `basicHttpBinding` for the `http://` scheme by default....

Comment: thanks, marc. you were right, I believe, on the fact that WCF 4 kicks in a default endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

If you had posted your service interface I could have said with certainty but I believe you have something like this on your service interface:

```
 [ServiceContract(SessionMode = SessionMode.Required)]
```

This would require session and `BasicHttpBinding` does not support it. You need to use wsHttpBinding if you need to have sessions.

Comment: the problem is that I am using wsHttpBinding in configuration file, not basicHttpBinding. you can see it in my web.config posted above.

Comment: the .svc file is in the c:\inetpub directory